# Implementing: udp receive queue dropping packets

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp, freebsd

How can I implement following scenario?

I want my FreeBSD kernel to drop UDP packets on high load.

I can set `sysctl` net.inet.udp.recvspace to very low number to drop the packet. But how do I implement such an application?

I assume I would need some kind of client/server application.

Any pointers are appreciated.

p.s. This is *not* a homework. And I am *not* looking for exact code. I am just looking for *ideas*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will do that automatically. You don't have to do anything about it at all, let alone fiddle with kernel parameters.

Most people posting about UDP are looking for ways to *stop* UDP from dropping packets!

Comment: lol! I know. I want to see it fail and then get fixed with net.inet.udp.recvspace.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF)` socket option via `setsockopt()` to change the size of your socket *buffer*.

Answer (score 0):

Either tweak the sending app to 'drop' the ocasional packet or, if not possible, connect the UDP messages via a proxy that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is do the following. I don't know if you need a kernel module or a program.

Supouse you have a function call when you receive an UDP datagram, and then you can choose what to do, drop it or process it. And the process function can trigger several threads.

```
EVER:
    DATAGRAM := DEQUE()
    IF(HIGHLOAD > LIMIT)
       SEND(HIGH_LOAD_TO(DATAGRAM.SOURCE))
       CONTINUE //Start from the biggining
    HIGLOAD := HIGHLOAD + 1 
    PROCESS(DATAGRAM)


PROCESS(DATAGRAM):
   ...PROCESS DATAGRAM...
   HIGHLOAD := HIGHLOAD - 1
```

You can tweek this how ever you want, but is an idea. When you start processing a pakcage, you count, and when the process is finished, you decrement. So you basically can choose how many packages are you processing right now.